# Binario a decimal en C, tengo un problema en este código

Tags: c, bucle-for, binario

Me piden hacer un programa para convertir una cadena de binario de 14 dígitos a decimal, por ejemplo: 11000010100011 = 12451, pero no sale cuando compilo el programa.

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------"
         "----\n");
  printf("Disenar un programa que permita convertir una cadena de 14 bits a "
         "decimal.\n\n");

  int bit, decimal, sum = 0, i, exp = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < 14; i++) {

    printf("Ingrese el numero en decimal digito por digito\n");
    scanf("%d", bit);

    sum = bit * pow(2, exp);

    decimal = sum + sum;

    exp = exp + 1;
  }

  printf("El numero en decimal es: %d\n", decimal);

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `decimal = sum + sum;` Aqui probablemente lo que tendrias que haber puesto es `decimal = decimal + sum;`. O aun mas corto `decimal += sum;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que encontré en tu programa es que falto el & para asignar a la variable bit **scanf(" %d", &bit);** ,además esta el tema del acumulador el cual esta mal definido, ya que solo estas duplicando el valor sum y asignándolo a la variable decimal, lo correcto como lo indica el colega es **decimal=decimal+sum**, con lo cual mantienes el valor que venia del ciclo anterior y le sumas el valor de la operación actual.

Adicional a esto le hice unas mejoras a tu código ya que hay variables superfluas tales como exp, el cual es un acumulador que  podemos usar directamente del ciclo for en el cual estamos; veamos el desarrollo.

[image: magen]

Puedes ver que la operación para hacer la conversión comienza en 0 y termina en 13, y asumiendo que el numero binario lo estas ingresando desde la izquierda hacia la derecha, entonces tu exp, también estaba mal definido ya que ejecutaba 1x2^1 en el primer ciclo, o sea estaba haciendo la operación al revés, para resolver esto realice un ciclo for ,pero a la inversa, o sea que comienza en 14 (que son los dígitos que ingresaras) y terminara en 1, y para la operatoria esta se ejecutará desde 13 a 0.

```
for (i = 13; i >= 0; i--) { }
```

quedando de la siguiente manera :

```c
int main() {
  printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------"
         "----\n");
  printf("Disenar un programa que permita convertir una cadena de 14 bits a "
         "decimal.\n\n");

  int bit, decimal=0, i;

  for (i = 13; i >= 0; i--) {

    printf("Ingrese el numero en decimal digito por digito\n");
    scanf(" %d", &bit);

    decimal = decimal + bit * pow(2, (i));
  }

  printf("El numero en decimal es: %d\n", decimal);

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```